# How to optimize if else statemants with many specifications

Tags: java, spring, if-statement, optimization

I am trying to create dynamic search based on fields send in request body.
I prepared many Specifications and in "summary specification" (which is called in method) I want to call them if field is different than null.
It works but the problem is I will never know which parameter will start creating condition so I had to add boolean parameter which resulted in the creation of many if else statements.
Code:

```
public Specification<ShapeEntity> conditionalSearch(ShapeParams shapeParams) {
    Specification spec = null;
    boolean isFirstParam = true;
    if (shapeParams.getType() != null) {
        if (isFirstParam) {
            spec = Specification.where(isTypeEqual(shapeParams.getType()));
            isFirstParam = false;
        } else {
            spec = spec.and(isTypeEqual(shapeParams.getType()));
        }
    }

    if (shapeParams.getWidthTo() != null) {
        if (isFirstParam) {
            spec = Specification.where(isWidthLessThan(shapeParams.getWidthTo()));
            isFirstParam = false;
        } else {
            spec = spec.and(isWidthLessThan(shapeParams.getWidthTo()));
        }
    }

    if (shapeParams.getWidthFrom() != null) {
        if (isFirstParam) {
            spec = Specification.where(isWidthGreaterThan(shapeParams.getWidthTo()));
            isFirstParam = false;
        } else {
            spec = spec.and(isWidthGreaterThan(shapeParams.getWidthTo()));
        }
    }
    return spec;
}
```

Is there any way to optimize it? Specification has to always start with ".where" as first, and next I can add other conditions and I would like to have even 10+ parameters.

Comment: You could look into using the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or something similar.  Where one strategy could call another strategy and you could kind of make a rules engine.  Overall the number of if statements will stay the same, they will just be placed into individual classes.

Comment: If by "optimalize" you mean make the code cleaner, you might want to post this on [codereview.se]. But you'll need to include more context and better explain what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some methods that receive some values to validate and return boolean.

```
boolean checkType(CustomObject type){
    return type == null;
}
```

You can check the use of Optional, it maybe helps with some if blocks.

```
Optional.ofNullable(type).ifPresent(t -> /*some operations*/);
```

You can check if you can merge some conditions.

```
if (shapeParams.getType() != null && isFirstParam) {
     //do something....
} else {
     //do other....    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to achieve.
If no criteria is provided and you want to search without any "WHERE" clause
you can do

```
public Specification<ShapeEntity> conditionalSearch(ShapeParams shapeParams) {
    Specification spec = Specification.where(null);
    if (shapeParams.getType() != null) {
        spec = spec.and(isTypeEqual(shapeParams.getType()));
    }

    if (shapeParams.getWidthTo() != null) {
        spec = spec.and(isWidthLessThan(shapeParams.getWidthTo()));
    }

    return spec;
}
```

and if you move if check into `isTypeEqual` returning null, you could directly call

```
 Specification spec = Specification.where(null);
 spec = spec.and(isTypeEqual(shapeParams.getType()));
```

If you would like to know if after all those "ands" specification is still null, only way I've found is something like this

```
public Specification<ShapeEntity> conditionalSearch(ShapeParams shapeParams) {
    Specification emptySpec = Specification.where(null);
    Specification spec = emptySpec;
    if (shapeParams.getType() != null) {
        spec = spec.and(isTypeEqual(shapeParams.getType()));
    }

    if (shapeParams.getWidthTo() != null) {
        spec = spec.and(isWidthLessThan(shapeParams.getWidthTo()));
    }
    if (spec == emptySpec) {
       return null;
    }
    return spec;
}
```